# Connect a bulb to switch

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches

Behind a switch socket, there are 4 wires. One has current, the rest don't show any charge when tested. Question is, how does one decide which wires to connect a bulb to. ? Common sense says take the live wire, and any other wire which does not show current. Is it true ? Or is their another way.

I need to connect a switch to the bulb and I am a layman in this context. Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Call an electrician! Don't mess with electricity if you don't know what you are doing. It will kill you in the end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about home repair, not electronics design.

Answer (score 8):

You are out of your depth. Get professional help.

> One has current, ...

No. One has voltage. There is no current until you connect it to the light.

> How does one decide which wires to connect a bulb to?

By understanding the circuits and, in this case, tracing the wiring and knowing where each wire is terminated. There are many different reasons there could be four wires at your switch "socket" (wall box).

> I need to connect a switch to the bulb and I am a layman in this context. Please advise.

Advice remains, "get help from someone qualified".